# Unable to run CentOs properly on my computer

Tags: centos, selinux

I am following this guide to install lamp: https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/how-to-install-a-lamp-stack-on-centos-7/#optional-test-and-troubleshoot-the-lamp-stack. I cannot run the following comands:

```
   sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/example.com -R 
   sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/example.com -R
```

because I get this errors:

```
[root@vps82008 ~]# sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/modul-cscart.com -R
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘index.html’
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘phptest.php’
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘public_html’
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘error.log’
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘access.log’
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘logs’
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ‘/var/www/html/modul-cscart.com’
```

What can I do? I completed the hole tutorial except this point. I can access my site via ip-adress but it won't show when I type modul-cscart.com

Comment: The errors you are seeing is because of some SELinux stuff, it might be useful for security but it has absolutely nothing to do with the issue you're experiencing with your website.  The reason your website doesn't work when using its domain is because the domain does not exist (yet).  Is it a brand new domain name?  It can take up to 48 hours or something (usually just a couple of hours) for DNS to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Oscar said, probably it's a DNS related problem, since you can access the site via IP.

Regarding SELinux, the files are unlabeled. The command should be like this:
`sudo chcon -R -h system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/example.com`

Have in mind that changes made by `chcon` will not persist a relabel. You should use `semanage` to make the changes permanent.

For example,
`sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/var/www/html/example.com(/.*)?"`

You can use the command `ls -Z` to check SELinux contents.